# Ant zipfileset to include files from a directory, but not if they are duplicated in another directory

Tags: ant, zip

I'm working on an ant target that takes as input a handful of directories and files produced by some up-stream targets, and outputs a zip file.

Thus, my target currently looks a little like this:

```
<target name="package-the-zip" depends="upstream-thing1, upstream-thing2">
    <!-- a little bit of tweaking happens here -->
    <zip destfile="myPackage.zip">
        <zipfileset dir="PARENT-DIR" prefix="myParent">
            <!-- a handful of include and exclude tags are here -->
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
</target>
```

As of now, PARENT-DIR/foo/ contains a handful of files- for example, call them a,b,c,d,e,f, and g.  Along with that,
PARENT-DIR/childDirA/foo/ contains a,b,e,g,x,y and PARENT-DIR/childDirB/foo/ contains b,c,e,f,q,r, and so on over several children.  In other words, each child's /foo/ contains some duplicates of the parent, and also one or two things unique to itself.  I want to eliminate the duplicates in the resulting zip.

I can accept either of these solutions based on the above example:

1. PARENT-DIR/foo/ contains a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x,y,q,r and each child's /foo/ is empty.
2. PARENT-DIR/foo/ contains a,b,c,d,e,f,g, childDirA/foo/ contains *only* x,y and childDirB/foo/ contains *only* q,r.

Some other info that maybe helpful:

- The number of child directories is small (<20) and should be stable, so acting on them individually is acceptable.
- The number of files in each /foo/ is large (~100) and subject to change, so listing them one by one is not a good solution.

Is there some combination of zipfileset patterns and selectors that will accomplish this?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, can you just move all the content in one 1 directory, which is solution #1. This will though overwrite the duplicates.
This should be done before <zip> so that what you include is a final set.

Comment: @saurabh14292 - Yes, that's the solution, and if you add `overwrite="false"` in the copy tag, it doesn't.  Then, you need to make sure you exclude the child libs in the zipfileset.  Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really Saurabh14292's answer, not mine.  He has seems to have chosen to not convert his comment to an answer, hence CW.

The solution is to copy the child files into the parent before zipping.  Copying adds unique files and ignores duplicates.  Then, when zipping, exclude the child files.  The snip in the question becomes:

```
<target name="package-the-zip" depends="upstream-thing1, upstream-thing2">
    <!-- a little bit of tweaking happens here -->
    <copy todir="PARENT-DIR/foo">
        <fileset dir="PARENT-DIR/childDirA/foo">
            <!-- include as needed -->
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- repeat copy for each child as needed -->
    <zip destfile="myPackage.zip">
        <zipfileset dir="PARENT-DIR" prefix="myParent">
            <!-- a handful of include and exclude tags are here -->
            <exclude name="PARENT-DIR/childDir*/foo" />
        </zipfileset>
    </zip>
</target>
```